# How to implement facebook share in my asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, market-share

Please how can I implement share button that can retrieve content from MySQL database to my facebook page using asp.net c#

Comment: There are usually hundreds of ways to implement something.    If you are having a more specific problem with what you already tried, please post that.   If you are having problems with programming, it would be better to post on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I need the code I can use to share content from my MySQL database to facebook page and am using asp.net, please help me out